# How to use update with prevent duplicate entries SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android

hell... I in my code prevent duplicate entries but when update any field in this row tell my this name exist Although I'm in same row 
as example have column firstName value = Mohamed ,column lastName value = taha and column Age value 25 when update Age tell my this firstName exist.
How to Solution this problem ?

This is my method:

```
public void saveStore(){
    String namePermission =ETNamePermission.getText().toString().trim();
    String notes = ETNotesPermission.getText().toString().trim();
    boolean isExist = dbHelper.isExistNamePErmission(namePermission);

    if ( intent == null && TextUtils.isEmpty(namePermission)|| TextUtils.isEmpty(namePermission) ){
        ETNamePermission.requestFocus();
        ETNamePermission.setError(getString(R.string.error_empty_text));
        return;
    }

    if (intent == null) {
        if (isExist ==true){
            ETNamePermission.requestFocus();
            ETNamePermission.setError(getString(R.string.error_exist_permission));
            return;
        }
        ItemsStore itemSavePErmission = new ItemsStore();
        itemSavePErmission.setNamePermission(namePermission);
        itemSavePErmission.setNotes(notes);
        if (itemSavePErmission == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.error_save_permission), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            dbHelper.addPermission(itemSavePErmission);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.save_permission), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }else {

        ItemsStore itemUpdatePermision = new ItemsStore();
        itemUpdatePermision.setId(intent.getInt(ID_PERMISSION));
        itemUpdatePermision.setNamePermission(namePermission);
        itemUpdatePermision.setNotes(notes);
        boolean isExistForUpdated = dbHelper.isNamePermissioneUsedDailyMovements(intent.getInt(ID_PERMISSION));
        if (isExistForUpdated == true){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.this_permission_not_updated), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (itemUpdatePermision != null){
            dbHelper.updatePermission(itemUpdatePermision);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.update_permission), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.error_update_permission), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sqlite` [`replace()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) method

```
db.replace(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

But your table should have a `unique` or `primary key`. And `replace` method will check if a row exist with the given `primary key`. If exist the it will replace with updated value, if not then it will insert a new row with the given values.

Check this [tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/) to learn about `replace()` method.

Comment: This is answer not true replace() do delete record then add record
, I need update record only with keep the same id

Comment: `replace` will delete only when conflicts in `unique` or `primary key`.  if your `id` is `primary key` then deleting and creating new will not change your `id`

Comment: my friend this answer not Solution  , as example I saved row name mohamed when saved another row the same name I need show message not save because the name exist ,How to do this?